# I want to run the libGDX-setup jar file how to do it

Tags: java, jar, libgdx, executable-jar

Whenever I type the following Command : 
**-jar libGDX-setup.jar** in Command Prompt .It Shows the below **error**

1.-jar' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

2.Whenever I type the command **libGDX-setup.jar** in the command prompt

Error:It displays the AlZip with the files present in it.

**Questions**

1.What is the  **location in which this jar file** must be placed.

2.How to **run the setup file** when I **double click or type the command.**

Comment: `-jar` and the name of a file are not commands in the Windows command prompt. Precede these with the `java` command.

Comment: Are you sure you have java installed? when you install java it automatically makes jars executable via double clicking them

Comment: Yes,I have the java installed

Comment: Can you tell me the path where I have to paste the libGDX.jar file

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
java -jar libGDX-setup.jar
```

command and make sure java is installed in your PC and path of java is defined in your system and added in Environment variable. In my PC path is

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\bin
```

It may be helpful, Thanks

Comment: Actually whether I have to locate the libGDX in bin folder?

Comment: java is in bin folder. **libGDX-setup.jar** jar is in your folder where you run this command.

Comment: I can't understand

Comment: In which path do I want to paste the libGDX.jar file

Comment: According to my understanding you want to run libGDX setup for new project creation ?? am i right ??

Comment: download zip from this link https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/  and unzip file that contain gdx-setup.jar . Run this jar and create new project. Your system need to be connected to internet so that it can download all dependency that required by your project. Import that project by gradle in Android Studio or IntellijIDEA . Thats all.

Comment: I'm not able to run the jar file to create a new project

Comment: **java -jar gdx-setup.jar** is full command and here gdx-setup is the name of that jar.

Comment: Can you explain me the path in which I have to place the jar file

Comment: which operating system are you using ??

Comment: windows 10 Operating system

Comment: keep it in any folder of your disk and run command from there using cmd prompt.

Comment: java -jar gdx-setup.jar

Comment: The system cannot find the file C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe.

Comment: I know it's quite late but if you are still looking for answer, you can copy java -jar gdx-setup.jar file to the location where you have your Java installed. This is required if you have not set up the Java path in environment variable in Windows. For you error, Windows is unable to find the java because either binary is not present at that location or the environment variable value is incorrect.